# friending istream operator with class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

hello i'm trying to overload my operator `>>` to my class but i ecnouter an error in eclipse.

code:

```
    friend istream& operator>>(const istream& is, const RAngle& ra){
    return is >> ra.x >> ra.y;
}
```

code2:

```
    friend istream& operator>>(const istream& is, const RAngle& ra)
{
    is >> ra.x;
    is >> ra.y;
    return is 
}
```

Both crash and i don't know why, please help.

EDIT:

`ra.x` & `ra.y` are both 2 private ints of my class;

Full error:

error:

```
   ..\/rightangle.h: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const RAngle&)':
..\/rightangle.h:65:12: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'is >> ra.RAngle::x'
..\/rightangle.h:65:12: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)}'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:126:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:126:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:133:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:241:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:241:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}'
..\/rightangle.h:66:12: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'is >> ra.RAngle::y'
..\/rightangle.h:66:12: note: candidates are:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:122:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:122:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type&) {aka std::basic_istream<char>& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>&)}'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:126:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:126:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<char>::__ios_type&) {aka std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)}'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:133:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:133:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:241:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>] <near match>
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/istream:241:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const int' to 'std::basic_istream<char>::__streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<char>*}''
```

Comment: We don't know either. What's `ra.x`? Also, entire error, along with overload set.

Comment: Please capitalize conventionally.

Comment: Since you're going to modify the `RAngle` parameter, it needs to be a *non*-const reference.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin- thank you this was the answere, it seems it works now pelase post your comment as an answere.

Comment: They don't **crash**, they **fail to compile**.

Comment: @user1388172 From your post: "Both crash and i don't know why"

Comment: *None* of the parameters can be const, *including* the stream. They are all modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `operator>>` is going to modify the parameters you pass to it, they cannot be references to const, so what you want is something like:

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, RAngle &ra) { 
    return is >> ra.x >> ra.y;
}
```

Note that almost any I/O operation also (at least potentially) changes the state of the stream, so you (nearly?) always want to pass stream parameters by non-const reference.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is in the signature of the operator:

```
friend istream& operator>>(const istream& is, const RAngle& ra){
//                         ^^^^^              ^^^^^
    return is >> ra.x >> ra.y;
}
```

If the arguments are `const` you will not be able to modify them. As of the error messages, they seem to indicate that the compiler is failing to find an appropriate overload for `is >> ra.x` and `is >> ra.y`. This might be related to the previous issue (cannot find an overload that takes a const-lvalue) or not, depending on what the types of `ra.x` and `ra.y` are (which is not shown in the question).

Comment: thank you. i specified they  are 2 private int's of Class `RAngle`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove const from the parameter "const RAngle& ra". You cannot modify a constant reference from a method.